# Purple screen after reinstalling grub multiple times

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-7

I recently dual booted my laptop with Windows 7 x64 and Ubuntu 14.04. I followed all the steps and now it seems Windows 7 only works when it wants to work. When it doesnt want to work it hangs on a purple screen. I have tried EVERYTHING! I have tried boot-repair and edited the grub2 conf file, and it still happens!! Can someone  please help?

UPDATE: I finally got into Windows 7 so this appears to be intermittent. I would still like to get this resolved if anyone cares to help.

UPDATE: Can someone please help?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some additional resources to fixing the Windows bootloader. This website offers detailed steps as to how to restore the MBR without killing grub2:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/